# Geting data from mysql to StreamBuilder Flutter

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, snapshot, stream-builder

I have an assignment and I have to take data from mysql server into a flutter and pass it to StreamBuilder and I was trying to use the same class we are using it in firebase and now I have problem with passing the data that I already take it from the server into the StreamBuilder and as I remember I have to use a different type of snapshot, any help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Server',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Server App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  get documents => null;




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future getData() async{
    var url = 'https://milk-white-reveille.000webhostapp.com/get.php';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data.toString());


  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
  }
}

class BookList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder(
      stream: _MyHomePageState.getData().snapshot(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<_MyHomePageState> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document['title']),
              subtitle: new Text(document['type']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },

    );

  }

}
```

The new code is this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Server',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Server App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
  Timer _timer;
  var data;

  Future getData() async {
    var url = 'https://milk-white-reveille.000webhostapp.com/get.php';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);


    String jsonsDataString = response.body.toString(); // toString of Response's body is assigned to jsonDataString
    data = jsonDecode(jsonsDataString);
    print(data.toString());
    //Add your data to stream
    _streamController.add(data);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();

    //Check the server every 5 seconds
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) => getData());

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //cancel the timer
    if (_timer.isActive) _timer.cancel();

    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: new _MySql()

          );

  }
}



class _MySql extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _MyHomePageState()._streamController.stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data((data) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(data['title']),
                  subtitle: Text(data['type']),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but on the phone screen loading... appearing 
this one from terminal 
`E/flutter (10194): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (10194): connected{"title":"maen","type":"dev"}`

Comment: so whats your exact problem then? Please show some error message or something.

Comment: now there is no error the hole problem with passing the data into the list from the snapshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use it periodically with StreamBuilder;

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Server',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Server App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  StreamController _streamController = StreamController();
  Timer _timer;

  Future getData() async {
    var url = 'https://milk-white-reveille.000webhostapp.com/get.php';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    //Add your data to stream
    _streamController.add(data);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();

    //Check the server every 5 seconds
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) => getData());

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //cancel the timer
    if (_timer.isActive) _timer.cancel();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _streamController.stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.map((document) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(document['title']),
                  subtitle: Text(document['type']),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          return Text('Loading...');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `FutureBuilder` instead of `StreamBuilder`. You don't need to use `StreamBuilder` for fetching data from the server, If you don't want to check server periodically. (If you want to use it periodically and with StreamBuilder check my next answer);

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Server',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Server App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future getData() async {
    var url = 'https://milk-white-reveille.000webhostapp.com/get.php';
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.map((document) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(document['title']),
                  subtitle: Text(document['type']),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          return Text('Loading...');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```