# how to force the server to respond as json

Tags: php

I had a problem with `StreamBuilder` in flutter app here [Geting data from mysql to StreamBuilder Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61419688/geting-data-from-mysql-to-streambuilder-flutter)

and now I want to force the server to pass the data as JSON this my php code
`db.php`

```
<?php

$dns = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=id13424627_flutter';
$user = 'id13424627_flutter_app';
$pass = 'Flutter_maen12';

try{
  $db = new PDO ($dns, $user, $pass);
  echo 'connected';
}catch( PDOException $e){
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    echo $error;
}
```

`get.php`

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM flutter';
$stm = $db->prepare($query);
$stm->execute();
$row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($row);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete this an `echo 'connected';` and add the top of your get.php file;

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```